# In spip, how to link to in-text footnote references to the same reference in the end-of-the-page footnote list?

Tags: reference, footnotes, spip

In SPIP 4.2, how can I force two in-text footnote references to link the the same end of the page footnote?

For example, how can I make the following in-text code: `Some text[[Reference 1]] and some more text[[Reference 1]].` show this

> Some text[1] and some more text[1].

instead of this:

> Some text[1] and some more text[2].

?

Answer (score 0):

In Spip, two in-text footnote references can be linked to the same end-of-the-page footnote by determining the number automatically given to the first footnote and placing this number in-between `<>` for any additional in-text footnote references.

For example:
`Some text[[Reference 1]] and some more text[[<1>]].` will give you this

> Some text[1] and some more text[1].